# Graph OAuthException 1500 : The url you supplied is invalid

Tags: facebook-graph-api, exception, oauth, feed

As of today, almost all of my app's calls to share links on user's feeds are failing with the following error:

```
{
    "message": "(#1500) The url you supplied is invalid",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 1500
}
```

Uisng PHP cURL, I'm posting to `https://graph.facebook.com/{user_id}/feed` and submitting a `link` parameter pointing to a valid, working URL (plus `message` params) etc.

Strangely, I can issue a command line cURL request and the request seems to work correctly (at least I haven't had an error yet).

I don't want to file a bug report yet incase I've missed something in a breaking migration. Any ideas as to what may be causing this?

Comment: Can the URL be shared manually on Facebook? Does the URL validate in [Facebook's Debug Tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug)?

Comment: @Igy - if I paste the URL directly into the status box it is scraped correctly. By entering the URL into the debugger I get "Direct creation of this object type is forbidden" ?

Comment: OK - have updated the og:type to 'website' and the debugger no longer reports errors, so I'll see if this resolves the problem.

Comment: @Igy - looks like that's fixed it (previously the og:type was 'photo'). Doesn't explain why it worked over commandline cURL but seems to be working now.

Comment: I had the same problem - was not passing the "type" and as soon as I added that, it works again.

Comment: I have the same issue, but it doesn't work for the first time, next time it is working as fine. any idea to fix this.

Comment: I've found the problem is still occurring randomly (although not as frequently as before). A very similar bug has been reported to Facebook so it may be useful to add yourself to the bug at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/136768399829531 .

Comment: I have the same problem as @RameshAkula.  First two posts to a new graph object fail with the above mentioned error message, and the third post goes through.  FB debugger shows no errors and all graph info is scraped correctly.

Comment: Added for reference. Current Reopen facebook bug here. https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/136768399829531

Answer (score 2):

http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/476666205677592

I have this problem too. it happened randomly. I'm sure the url I supplied is valid and can not reproduce it. So reported bug here..

Comment: ah. this can not be counted as a answer. but I can't find "add comment" link on your post..

Answer (score 2):

```
Erro While FB Publish: {contents = "(#1500) The url you supplied is invalid"}

Solution:
1. Go to: https://www.facebook.com/
2. Click on Setting > manage app
3. Select "Edit App" button
4. Select "Permission" under the "Setting" panel at left side
5. Make Auth Token Parameter:  To "URI Fragment(#access_token=…)"  
6. Click "Save Changes" button.

Its fixed now!!!
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution for me was:

1) I uploaded photo to my facebook user account

```
$fb->setFileUploadSupport(true);
$fb->setAccessToken('access token of my user (just to post an image)');
var_dump($fb->api('/me/photos', 'POST', ['image' =>'@F:\\fb\\fb_2.jpg','msg' =>'sss']));
```

2) After that set access for this picture to "For everyone" on my facebook page.

3) Then took var_dumped `id` to url `https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid={var_dumped id}`

4) For every user, authorized my app, the following code started work normally `$fb->api('/' . $fbuserid . '/feed', 'POST', [ 'link' => 'https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid={var_dumped id}', 'message' => 'my post', 'type'=>'photo']);`